# Use of uninitialized value after fetchrow()

Tags: sql, perl, sqlite

I am running:

```
my $config = "";
my $dsn = "dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db";
my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
    $dsn, 
    "",
    "",
    { RaiseError => 1}
) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT config FROM tests WHERE status=1");
$sth->execute();    
my $config = $sth->fetchrow();
if($config ne "")
{
    print "found!"
}
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Why I'm getting

```
Use of uninitialized value $config in string ne at .....
```

Comment: Turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Likely `fetchrow` is returning undef. Why are you testing for it being a null string anyway?

Comment: I am adding `use strict; use warnings; use DBI;` to my code

Comment: Is `config` null in the database?

Comment: Reason I mention it - you've got `my $config` in there twice.

Comment: @AKHolland, yes. $config is null in database

Comment: @Sobrique, I want to know the result of my select query. So i'm checking if the record exist or not

Comment: So could you just test `defined` (or `truth` of) of $config?

Comment: `fetchrow` is alias of `fetchrow_array`, and here is some info about [calling the method in scalar context](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no documented `fetchrow`. You should use `fetchrow_array` instead.

The problem is that `DBI` returns a value of `undef` for values set to `NULL` in the database. So `my $config = $sth->fetchrow_array` sets `$config` to `undef` *either* if there are no matching rows found in the table, *or* if the row found has a value of `NULL` for `config`. That means it can't be used to test whether there are any matching rows in the table. Also, you cannot compare an `undef` value as if it was a string -- it will raise the error you saw

```
Use of uninitialized value $config in string ne
```

so you need to test whether `fetchrow_array` returns an empty list, or if `fetchrow_arrayref` returns an undefined value.

Your code should be either

```
my @config = $sth->fetchrow_array;
if (@config) {
    print "found!"
}
```

or

```
my $config = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref;
if (defined $config) {
    print "found!"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. both gives me the same error again

Comment: That can't be true: the first example has no `$config`

Comment: `fetchrow` works fine as an alias for `fetchrow_array`. Checking an undefined value against a string with warnings enabled is his issue.

Comment: Sorry. yes. the first one works. but the second has the same issue.

Comment: Now both works with your edited version. but where was the issue?

Comment: @AKHolland: It is best not to use `fetchrow` as it is undocumented. The original code also leaves `$config` set to undef if there are no more records, or if there is a record that has `config` set to NULL. That is why the result of `fetchrow_array` should always be assigned to an array.

Comment: @NimaSoroush: I've added to my solution to explain.

Comment: @Borodin I don't use it myself, just that it is plainly not his problem, and that's the only thing this answer said originally.